# LINQ SELECT from a list and using a WHERE

Tags: c#, linq

How do I correctly write this LINQ statement?  I have this list (outfalls) of class Outfall.  It works without the WHERE clause.  When I added the WHERE it throws a NullReferenceException.

```
outfalls = outfalls
    .Select(x => new Outfall { loc_name = x.sys_loc_code, planned_task_code = x.planned_task_code })
    .Where(x => x.planned_task_code.Contains("DAILY"))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Your `Select` returns an `IEnumerable<Outfall>`, where each `Outfall` only has its `loc_name` field populated. Thus, `planned_task_code` is null and calling `Contains` throws the exception appropriately.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Why not post that as an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: @EthanTheBrave Did you see the second comment, where I say the question is a duplicate? One should not answer duplicate questions. Now it's been closed as such.

Comment: ah I modified it to set the planned_task_code but it's still throwing the same error.  please see the updated question

Comment: If `x.planned_task_code` is `null`, you'll still get the exception

Comment: You can modify your code to check for `null`, like: `.Where(x => x.planned_task_code != null && x.planned_task_code.Contains("DAILY"))` or simply: `.Where(x => x.planned_task_code?.Contains("DAILY") ?? false)`

Comment: @HereticMonkey I did not. That makes more sense then! :)

Comment: @PauloCampez If `x.planned_task_code` is `null`, then calling `Contains` on it will throw an exception. Also, `("DAILY" ?? string.Empty).ToString()` doesn't do anything to change the existing code at all. `"DAILY"` is not `null`, so `string.Empty` will never be used. Also, no need to call `ToString()` on a `string`.